# Obtaining an array of values for coupled nonlinear equations by iterating over input arrays

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I am attempting to solve a coupled system of nonlinear equations:

x(x+2y)/(1-x-y) = A

y(x+2y)/x = B

where A and B are elements in two different arrays of identical size.

I have 10,000 values for A in an array, and 10,000 values for B in another array.

I need to determine x[i] and y[i] using A[i] and B[i].  However, when I do the following:

```
def Eqs(z):
    x, y = z
    for i in A and B:
        return (x*(x + 2*y) - A[i]*(1 - x - y), y*(x + 2*y) - B[i]*x)

x, y = scopt.fsolve(Eqs, (1,1))
```

I get the following error message:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Using random arrays of appropriate size for A and B, Could someone please (1) explain why I'm getting that particular error message, and (2) suggest a work-around?

Answer (score 2):

The line `for i in A and B:` doesn't make much sense. `A and B` is a binary logical operation on the arrays `A` and `B`, which is neither valid nor the operation you need.

What you want to do is probably something like `for a, b in zip(A, B):`. This yields the scalars `a` and `b` in every iteration. So a = A[i] and b = B[i]. `zip` creates pairs of values from `A` and `B`, which are than available as `a` and `b` within the for-loop.

Alternatively you can iterate using the index `i`: `for i in range(len(A)):`

---

There is another issue with the code: `return` will stop the loop and leave the method in the very first iteration. So you either create two lists for the return values, fill it throughout the for-loop and return it at the end of `Eqs`. Or you shorten it using list comprehensions:

```
return [x*(x + 2*y) - a*(1 - x - y) for a in A], [y*(x + 2*y) - b*x for b in B]
```

This should yield two lists.

Comment: Would this return an array of x values and an array of y values?  I am ultimately needing to plot x and y as two functions of a and b, so I'll need to be obtaining 10,000 x-values and 10,000 y-values.

Comment: You beat me to it... I was going to ask about list comprehensions!  :)